# How to efficiently find pairs of unconnected edges on larger graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to find pairs of unconnected edges on larger graph using networkx library. However I am getting out of memory error.
Here is the example

```
G8=nx.read_edgelist('myfile.txt',create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)

negative=list(nx.non_edges(G8))
```

how to do this efficiently in python?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question: [Memory problems while code is running (Python, Networkx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252954/memory-problems-while-code-is-running-python-networkx)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a pair of unconnected edges?  Also, how large is the network?  How may edges/nodes?  It looks like you're finding a list of all node pairs that aren't in the graph.  This is probably a very large list.

Comment: @joel, the graph have 6454 Nodes and 24097 edges, Yes, finding a list of all node pairs that aren't in the graph, is there any alternatives?

Comment: It's not clear why you're finding this list.  It will have 6454*6453/2 - 24097 pairs.  That's around 21 million pairs.  What do you plan to do with it?